# Tikz Coordinate Fraction Reasoning

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

In my code, I defined the following:

```
\def\ctrlHeight{5};
\def\ctrlHeightSpacing{5/32 * \ctrlHeight};
```

And I did this:

```
\draw($(regWrtWire -| buff3.west) + (0, \ctrlHeightSpacing/2 cm)$) -- ($(regWrtWire -| buff3.east) + (0, 0.5*\ctrlHeightSpacing cm)$);
```

Output:

[image]

In the image, the left part is below the right part, in which it is in the correct position. When I multiply by 0.5 instead of dividing by 2, the output gives me

[image]

What could be the reason?

On a side note, if I do

```
\def\ctrlHeightSpacing{5*\ctrlHeight/32};
```

I get an incorrect value instead of 5*5/32 = 0.78125, which is supposed to be the correct value. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you make a complete example?

Comment: The file that I was referring is super big, I will create a simpler example later.

Comment: The reason is obvious. In `\draw($(regWrtWire -| buff3.west) + (0, \ctrlHeightSpacing/2 cm)$) -- ($(regWrtWire -| buff3.east) + (0, 0.5*\ctrlHeightSpacing cm)$);` in the left coordinate `(0, \ctrlHeightSpacing/2 cm)` you divide `\ctrlHeightSpacing` by `2cm`. In the right coordinate you multiply `\ctrlHeightSpacing` by 0.5. When pgf divides a distance by 2cm, it converts the distance to pt and divides the result by 2cm ~ 59pt. This is what you get.

Comment: If I were to divide by 2 (e.g. `\ctrlHeightSpacing/2`) should i use the {} delimiter?

Comment: No, you should use brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it is not very entertaining to bake a minimal example from fragments, and stating that the document is big is not a good excuse to let others do all the work. But in your case the behavior is not due to undisclosed code pieces. Rather, it is just because pgf computes what you want it to compute following its rules (which make a lot of sense at least to me). You probably want the computation in the blue path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\ctrlHeight{5}%<- a semicolon here is unnecessary
\def\ctrlHeightSpacing{5/32 * \ctrlHeight}%<- this is also a strange 
% practice. It would make more sense to say
% \pgfmathsetmacro\ctrlHeightSpacing{5/32 * \ctrlHeight}
\node[minimum width=2cm] (buff3){};
\coordinate (regWrtWire);
\draw($(regWrtWire -| buff3.west) + (0, \ctrlHeightSpacing/2 cm)$) -- ($(regWrtWire -| buff3.east) + (0, 0.5*\ctrlHeightSpacing cm)$);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yleft}{\ctrlHeightSpacing/2 cm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yright}{0.5*\ctrlHeightSpacing cm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\onecm}{1cm}
\path (-1,-1) node[text width=0.8\textwidth,align=left,anchor=north west]
{On the left side, you get 
$\displaystyle\frac{\ctrlHeightSpacing}{2\,\mbox{cm}}=
\frac{25/32}{2\cdot\onecm\,\mbox{pt}}=\yleft\,$pt (because pgf always converts
dimensionful quantities to something that is linear in pt) and 
on the right side
$0.5*\ctrlHeightSpacing\,\mbox{cm}=\displaystyle\frac{25}{64}\cdot\onecm\,\mbox{pt}=\yright\,\mbox{pt}$.};
% you probably want
\draw[blue]($(regWrtWire -| buff3.west) + (0,{( \ctrlHeightSpacing/2)*1 cm})$) -- ($(regWrtWire -| buff3.east) + (0, 0.5*\ctrlHeightSpacing cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]